# MySQL Auto Increment No Duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If I run the below query then use the AUTO_INCREMENT variable to post to table1 right afterwards, what are the chances that 2 users run the query at the same time and obtain identical auto increment values?

Is it very unlikely that this would happen?

```
$query = "SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
              FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
              WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db1'
              AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'table1'";

$result =  $link->query($query);
$numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

while($var2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

   $autoIncr = $var2['AUTO_INCREMENT'];
}



$query = "INSERT INTO table1(id,firstName)
          VALUES('$autoIncr','$firstName')";
```

Comment: "what are the chances that 2 users run the query at the same time and obtain identical auto increment values?" - it depends upon how many requests per minute is made by the users. For example, if there is only 1 user, the probability is 0.

Comment: Why don't use just define the appropriate field as auto-increment in the table definition ?

Comment: So like: `$query = "INSERT INTO table1(id,firstName) VALUES('','$firstName')";` then `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` ?

Comment: Let the database do what's it's designed to do, and don't play the odds on duplicates by trying to do it yourself

Comment: I'm going to run this after the query `$autoIncr =    $link->insert_id;` from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp

Answer (score 2):

Rather like

```
create table table1
( 
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  fullName varchar(100) not null
);
```

Then in the inserts

```
insert table1 (fullName) values('Fred Smith');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer to get a unique AI value:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table1(id,firstName)
          VALUES('','$firstName')";

$result =       $link->query($query);
$autoIncr =     $link->insert_id;   //Gets id of last inserted row
```